# Writing to a pipe is not working after many fork

Tags: c, fork, pipe, ipc

I have following testing program, I which I like to send(write) the data from deepest-child to the parent.

Code is:

```
#define M1 "Message One"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int f1[2];
char buff[32];

pipe(f1);

if (fork() == 0) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("%s :%d\n", "f1[0] :",f1[0]);
            while(read(f1[0], buff, sizeof(buff)) > 0)
                 printf("%s\n", buff);
                     return 0;
         } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }

} else {    
    sleep(2);
    printf("%s :%d\n", "f1[1] :",f1[1]);
    if(write(f1[1], M1, sizeof(M1) < 0))
    printf("%s\n","Error");
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code is, the  program is not printing the message.

I am not sure if this is related with many fork.

Answer (score 2):

Close the unused file descriptors it will work fine

In the inner most child

```
close(f1[1]);
```

In the parent process

```
close(f1[0]);
```

And also syntax error in the line write is called change it to

```
write(f1[1], M1, sizeof(M1)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

change your `if` statement to

```
if (write(f1[1], M1, sizeof(M1)) < 0)
```

instead of

```
if(write(f1[1], M1, sizeof(M1) < 0))
```